# Flex 3 Alert text doesn't stretch to fill space?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

This seems like a ridiculously simple question, and yet I just can't seem to find an answer.

I'm trying to display some simple information in an Alert (I'd rather not use an alert, but I need a fast n' simple solution for a project that's got to be out the door asap)

Long story short, no matter how large I make the alert, my information never stretches out, and ends up being clipped.

I can actually scroll through the text with the mousewheel, but that's no good.

The image says it all. Any ideas how to get around this? I can't imagine Alert just doesn't handle this.

Image here:

http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/3/bigalert.png

(I'm still a new user, can cannot add it directly)

Code:

```
var myAlert:Alert = Alert.show("The package you have selected includes a feature(s) you’ve already selected. \nWe have removed the individual features for you.");
myAlert.height = 150*2;
myAlert.width = 350*2;
```

Comment: Yeah, something is totally wrong with the way you are calling Alert.  It should not stretch like that.  Can you paste some code?

Comment: Not that it _should_ be doing that, but a workaround might be to use Panel or TitleWindow instead. Since you're in a hurry....

Comment: That's likely what I'll be doing. I just figured I'd toss this out to try and understand the problem, and see if a solution cropped up while I was working on my other outstanding items.

Comment: Do you have any special css for the Alert?

Comment: No, I didn't have anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution.

```
import mx.core.mx_internal;
use namespace mx_internal;

private function showAlert():void {
    var myAlert:Alert = Alert.show("The package you have selected includes a feature(s) you’ve already selected. \nWe have removed the individual features for you.");
    myAlert.height = 150*2;
    myAlert.width = 350*2;
    callLater(function():void {
        var textField:IUITextField =  IUITextField(myAlert.mx_internal::alertForm.mx_internal::textField);

        var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        textFormat.align = "center";

        textField.width = myAlert.width;
        textField.x = 0;
        textField.setTextFormat(textFormat);
    });
}
```

Comment: I'll have to go back and try this to see if it works (I've just hacked up a TitleWindow workaround, but this looks like it would work).